# Ionic - Unable to emulate or run android build on Windows 7 machine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a test project based on the tabs project template succesfully.
I then added the android platform succesfully
But when I try either running the project or emulating it, it seems to be always stuck on run.bat. I don't see any error and nothing happens.

I have made sure Java, ANT and the Android SDK are installed and their corresponding PATH and environment variables have been setup as per the docs. I have also uninstalled and re-installed everything but it's still the same.

```
*E:\Workspaces\Webstorm\arghwork>ionic emulate android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" E:\Workspaces\Webstorm\arghw
ork\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js E:\Workspaces\Webstorm\arghwor
k
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" E:\Workspaces\Webstorm\arghw
ork\hooks\after_prepare\020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js E:\Workspaces\Webstorm
\arghwork
Running command: E:\Workspaces\Webstorm\arghwork\platforms\android\cordova\run.b
at --emulator*
```

Comment: Sounds strange; it should work fine if you have followed the doc's steps. Did you try emulating/running command prompt **as Administrator** of the system? I would suggest you to run the command after starting cmd as an admin. If that doesn't help, uninstall everything(node, cordova, and Ionic), restart your PC and then install them again in CLI in admin mode. Re-check your paths and then try to emulate/run

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cordova cli instead :

- Add the platform in case it's not already done

  cordova platform add android
- build the project and run in the emulator

  cordova run android

A ionic project is basically a cordova project, so use the cordova cli for anything not ionic specific.

Comment: same problem with the cordova cli too